# Intel 10th Gen Comet Lake Graphics Driver Issues

Tags: debian, docker, intel

I was wondering if anyone could help point me in the right direction, I'm having problems with the Intel drivers on **Debian** as I'm trying to do some transcoding within Docker. But before I even get to Docker, I'm having issues.

**vainfo** was trying to open Trying to open **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so**, which I believe is the pre 8th Gen drivers. So I ran export **LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=iHD** and installed the following driver **intel-media-va-driver-non-free**.

When I look in **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri** I find the driver **iHD_drv_video.so**, but running vainfo keeps showing the following though.

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: can't connect to X server!
libva info: VA-API version 1.4.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: User requested driver 'iHD'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_4
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 1
vaInitialize failed with error code 1 (operation failed),exit
```

If anyone could be of assistance, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You must have the intel-vaapi-driver package installed in order to utilize VA hardware acceleration for an Intel iGPU.

Now you haven't specified your Debian version but https://packages.debian.org/source/bullseye/intel-vaapi-driver should work.

You won't need to specify any environment variables to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's greatly appreciated.  I will try this later today and report back! Just for reference system details are, **Operating System:** Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster), **Kernel:** Linux 5.7.0-0.bpo.2-amd64

Comment: Looks like I get a whole new error, similar to the last but vainfo: intel_memman.c:38: intel_memman_init: Assertion `intel->bufmgr' failed.  I have had this error before and haven't found the solution to it.

Comment: Debian stable software stack is quite outdated. Ether upgrade packages from Debian testing (mesa*, kernel*, *firmware*, intel-vaapi-driver) or use another distro. You'll also need firmware for your iGPU.